# How to check that voter has voted once and cannot cast another vote until next election?

Tags: php, android

I want to make an android app of electronic voting (e-voting).I have developed all things but stuck at these points

1. how to check that voter has voted once and cannot cast another vote until next election
2. how can I manage elections like election 2015 next election 2016 from remote database.
3. I want to control these things from my remote server

So what should I use sessions in **android or sessions/cookies** in php WebService or any built in API for voting?

Comment: I guess this question should be in  [quora](http://www.quora.com/), Stackoverflow is the place for helping people solving in issue regarding codes and not about giving suggestions !

Comment: yes surely i need code on a button's onclick listener how can i identify that user has voted once (my database is on a remote server)

Comment: and how can i manage that for next election voters can vote again .clearing all previous vote checks

Comment: I guess you are a mobile developer. And it shall be validated from server side itself. If you wanted to do it from mobile side. Then you shall just have this condition `if($uservoted==1)` the user is voted already. However you should have saved it in db once the user voted previously (This is just like a flag ) ;P

Comment: how can i use a unique id in db and update user using this unique id (using shared prefrences ) and updating shared prefrence data from remote db

Comment: You will have to get all the values from server side and stored it in [shared preferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) by key, For sure there will be unique id for each entry, and you can check the id's vote field has the flag are not

Comment: well thank u @SulthanAllaudeen can u plz post a example code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  do that in this way:

**Step 1 :**

Get the all the values of user from the server side and store it in the Shared Preferences

Just like

Using tinydb(It's for Example and you can use any way that you prefer)

```
TinyDB tinydb = new TinyDB(context);
```

to put

tinydb.putList("MyUsers", mUsersArray);

and to get

```
tinydb.getList("MyUsers");
```

or this way

```
public boolean saveArray(String[] array, String arrayName, Context mContext) {   
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();  
    editor.putInt(arrayName +"_size", array.length);  
    for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)  
        editor.putString(arrayName + "_" + i, array[i]);  
    return editor.commit();  
}
```

**Step 2 :**

Load the saved data

And You can Load it like

```
public String[] loadArray(String arrayName, Context mContext) {  
    SharedPreferences prefs = mContext.getSharedPreferences("preferencename", 0);  
    int size = prefs.getInt(arrayName + "_size", 0);  
    String array[] = new String[size];  
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)  
        array[i] = prefs.getString(arrayName + "_" + i, null);  
    return array;  
}
```

or

```
tinydb.getList("MyUsers");
```

And there you can do the comparison like

```
if(MyUsers['flag']==1)
{
//Already vote casted
}
else
{
//Vote not casted
}
```

**Case 1 :**

If the user didn't cast vote allow the user to caste and store the `$flag` value as `1` and send it to the server side to store it in the database.

**Case 2 :**

If the user already casted the vote then disable the vote button

**Note :**

I have given you the basic idea and you shall get the logic from here and implement your own style ;)